# Converting single line to multiple lines in perl

Tags: perl

I have file as below.

```
ID || DATE || AMOUNT
XX||20130801@@20130901@@20131001@@20131101||100@@200@@300@@400
```

and I want the output as below using perl.

```
xx||20130801||100

xx||20130901||200

xx||20131001||300

xx||20131101||400
```

Please help me how to convert using perl.

Comment: where does your attempt fail?

Comment: Don't get disappointed by the downvotes. Read stack overflow faqs before posting questions here. This a brutal place if you don't do your homework.

Comment: Did you really mean to change `XX` to `xx` or is that just a typo?

Comment: It is just typo error. I need the XX only

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -F'\|\||@@' -lanE'$.>1 or $" ="||",next; say "@F[0,$_,$_+4]" for 1..4' file
```

Comment: appreciate your one-liners. But this hard-codes for 4 entries. Even though OP doesn't mention it, I believe command should be generic for any number of entries.

Comment: @jkshah `for 1..$#F/2` solves this problem

Comment: now I must say your solution is masterpiece!

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -F'\|\|' -lane '@a=split(/@@/,$F[1]); @b=split(/@@/,$F[2]); print "$F[0]||$a[$_]||$b[$_]" foreach 0..$#a;' file
```

Output:

```
ID || DATE || AMOUNT
XX||20130801||100
XX||20130901||200
XX||20131001||300
XX||20131101||400
```

Comment: always use foreach instead of map in void context, as it's misleading

Comment: @mpapec thanks for your suggestion. updated ans. I was wondering whether there's any difference between `foreach` and `for`. You seem to use `for` in your code and both works fine.

Comment: +1, use whatever you like, they are synonyms http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops